# UML Diagram to Model API

Tags: api, uml, diagram, modeling

I need to create a diagram to document a RESTFul API that build, which UML diagram should I use?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @AboutDev Can Anybody provide me a link to an example or sample modeling of APIs, like Java API may be, using sequence diagrams?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Sequence diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm) are a good start. But you're better off reading about the different [types of diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) to see what your boss/prof etc want.

Comment: I was thinking in using a communication diagram, but a sequence diagram also seems feasible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 20):

A **sequence diagram** shows the *dynamics* of a system. So, if you want to show the flow of calls that will occur when clients call your API, then that's your choice.

A **class diagram** shows the *structure* of a system. So, if you want to show the method/function signatures of your API and how they are distributed across types, then this is what you should use.

Or you could use both to depict different views of your API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment =) 

I think a combination of both will be the winner =)

Comment: You're welcome. In my experience, most function-oriented APIs are better documented as class diagrams, using classes as "modules" or "components" to arrange the functions in groups, and looking at the API functions as methods. That offers a better level of granulaity on the API than a dynamics-oriented diagram such a sequence diagram.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want to convey, but when showing an API the [sequence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) is my go to diagram.